# Would I get away with releasing an unfinished app?

Tags: ios

So I'm going to do an app.  It will have about 100 recipes, and so far I've only done 4. I need to have it submitted to the App Store tomorrow.

My question is, if I'm not done by then, could I get away with just polishing what I have and then submitting it?  Would Apple or my customers hate my client?

Comment: Is there a way to pull recipes over the air or does that require an update?

Comment: This question will get closed here, but might be appropriate for programmers.stackexchange.com (although I don't participate there so don't really know).

Comment: @DeepYellow Not really. It would fit more into appstoreguessing.stackexchange

Comment: @JustSid :-) True. I didn't want to make a judgement call on the reception the question would get on programmers though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very rare in software development to release an application without a few known defects, so long as those defects are not critical to the functionality of the application itself.  This is why versioned releases exist.  That being said, unless you have a clear understanding of what your client wants, via a customer statement, it may be hard to determine whether or not your client will respond in a positive manner.

If you're down to a crunch, polish up what you've got, make sure it works, and cross your fingers.  Your other option would be to request pushing back the release date.

4 out of a 100 probably wont cut it though.  :P

Comment: Well, I had all this time.  I've been slacking.

Comment: @moonman239 Shouldn't your real concern be your client instead of the AppStore and its customers?